# How do I send bitcoin to multiple recipients at once?

Tags: wallet, transaction-fees, privacy

How do I send bitcoin to multiple recipients at once? Like [this](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transaction/506c19f7748d8de0a8a34db84976bcae0f008ff242a0ca3c7cfe75e8f9fc7557). Also, I would like to know if the reason I see people do this is for privacy reasons? As when I sell items online they usually send the btc to multiple recipients at once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can "*send to many*" addresses in the same transaction, most of the wallets have options to create a transaction with *multiple output addresses*.

> Also, I would like to know if the reason I see people do this is for privacy reasons?

There can be lot of reasons. Batching is normally done by exchanges and businesses to use bitcoin in a better way and pay less fees. I am not sure if there is any benefit related to privacy in batching except if the outputs are of similar amounts or amounts are hidden in the case of L-BTC(Liquid) confidential transactions.

**Batching can save upto 80% fees** by [David Harding](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/21052/david-a-harding): https://bitcointechtalk.com/saving-up-to-80-on-bitcoin-transaction-fees-by-batching-payments-4147ab7009fb

*Electrum:*

[image: electrum]

*Bitcoin Core:*

[image: Bitcoin-Core]